# mCustomScrollbar function not found

Tags: javascript, jquery, prototype

I don't know if this is common behaviour or if I'm the only one having this .. 
Here is my situation:

---

I have been using the `mCustomScrollbar` plugin for a long time for my drop down and it was amazing. Now I have more divs to apply the same plugin on, but the surprise is I'm always getting the following JS error

> Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function

and started to have unstable behaviour for the drop down (sometimes I get the scroll bar and sometimes I don't).

I don't know what code to include to make it more clear. Is there something I'm missing? what could be the problem?

Thanks in advance

Comment: did you update any jQuery? are you including all js files right before the closing `</body>` tag? have those included js files the right order, jQuery first, then the plugin then your `main.js` file? you could also try to include all external js like jquery and mCustomScrollbar in one "all_js.js" file

Comment: Thank you for your response, yes all included and all working fine ..  no errors even for the drop down .. actually the new divs are comming by an ajax call and shown as a popup .. I don't know if this changes any thing.